# Disappearing row after string split

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub, strsplit

I have a column of coordinates that I am splitting with `strsplit()` and removing unwanted character from with `gsub()`.  Note that there are **3034 rows**.

```
> head(bike_parking$Geom)
[1] "(37.7606289177, -122.410647009)" "(37.752476948, -122.410625009)" 
[3] "(37.7871729481, -122.402401009)" "(37.7776039475, -122.422764009)"
[5] "(37.7658325695, -122.46649784)"  "(37.7693399479, -122.432820008)"

> length(bike_parking$Geom)
[1] 3034

 > sum(is.na(bike_parking$Geom))
[1] 0
```

For some reason, after I run

```
dat <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(gsub("[()]", "", bike_parking$Geom)), split = ",")))
```

I am left with **3033**.  How did that happen and what steps do I take to figure out what went wrong?

```
> head(dat)
             X1              X2
1 37.7606289177  -122.410647009
2  37.752476948  -122.410625009
3 37.7871729481  -122.402401009
4 37.7776039475  -122.422764009
5 37.7658325695   -122.46649784
6 37.7693399479  -122.432820008

> nrow(dat)
[1] 3033
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't be the problem, but could it be that one element does not contain a comma `,`?

Comment: perhaps but how could I check for that and where it is happening?

Comment: Use `grep(",", bike_parking$geom)`

Comment: That produces : `grep(",", bike_parking$geom)
integer(0)`

Comment: So that's not the problem

Comment: `$Geom` or `$geom`? What does `grep(",", bike_parking$Geom, invert=TRUE)` return?

Comment: That worked, thanks

Comment: Why not extract the two values with `extract(dat, Geom, into = c("X1", "X2"), "(-?\\d*\\.?\\d+).*?(-?\\d*\\.?\\d+)")`? If there is just a whitespace with a comma missing, that would work with all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your strings do not have the same structure everywhere. You will somehow have to know which structure they all have in common to split them properly. From the comments below the question, I derive that some strings may not contain a comma to split the coordinates. You can remove all commas and split the strings at the empty space instead. I'll post a solution in base R and a solution with the `stringr`-package.

**Option 1: Base R:**
We can remove the parentheses and commas from your strings by using `gsub()`. Then we can split the strings at the space using `strsplit()`. The result will be:

```
splitted <- strsplit(gsub("[(),]", "", bike_parking$Geom), " ")
# [[1]]
# [1] "37.7606289177"  "-122.410647009"
# [[2]]
# [1] "37.752476948"   "-122.410625009"
# [[3]]
# [1] "37.7871729481"  "-122.402401009"
# [[4]]
# [1] "37.7776039475"  "-122.422764009"
# [[5]]
# [1] "37.7658325695" "-122.46649784"
# [[6]]
# [1] "37.7693399479"  "-122.432820008"
```

We have to reorganise these results a bit, so you'll end up with a data.frame with two columns:

```
sapply(1:2, function(x) sapply(splitted, `[[`, x))
#      [,1]            [,2]            
# [1,] "37.7606289177" "-122.410647009"
# [2,] "37.752476948"  "-122.410625009"
# [3,] "37.7871729481" "-122.402401009"
# [4,] "37.7776039475" "-122.422764009"
# [5,] "37.7658325695" "-122.46649784" 
# [6,] "37.7693399479" "-122.432820008"
```

**Option 2: Stringr:** This package contains a function `str_split()` (*not* `strsplit()`!), that allows you to skip the last step in the base R solution, because you can immediately get a data.frame instead of a list with vectors:

```
str_split(gsub("[(),]", "", bike_parking$Geom), " ", simplify=TRUE)
```